# Use openpyxl load_workbook in read_only mode to load workbook a that is opened in Excel on windows

Tags: python, excel, windows

I am currently trying to load a workbook an read its data with openpyxl on windows. The thing is that I would like to do it even if the workbook is already opened in Excel.

For now, I get a PermissionError even when I'm using `load_workbook(filename=filename, read_only=True)`.

I read that it was impossible to write data on an opened file on windows, contrary to POSIX based OSs. Is it also true for reading data?

Comment: Tell Excel to open it in share mode.

Comment: The problem is that I am not the person concerned. The objective is that users can do it without having to mess too much with Excel's settings.

Comment: You missunderstood the option `read_only=True`, this is for saving memory and prevents `openpyxl` to save afterwards. General, **you can't overcome locking, if the locking app does not allow to share**!

Comment: In that case, I think my problem does not have any easy solution.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to read excel workbooks into python when the workbooks are open in [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) Calc. LibreOffice is an open source alternative to MS Office, with Calc being the spreadsheet tool in LibreOffice. Apparently, Calc doesn't lock the workbooks when they are open.